# How to use dplyr::filter() to return only rows where the value contains one or more of a given vector of strings?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing a column of strings, and I want to use filter() (or another pipeable function) to return only rows containing strings that contain any of the values in another vector of strings. I have looked at previous questions and answers but can't find anything that's quite what I'm looking for.

For example:

```
   title <- c("apple pie", "fish pie", "peach strudel", "banana split", "chocolate cake", "pasta", "peaches and cream", "baked apples")
    recipes <- data.frame(cbind(c(1:8), title))

    fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "peach", "orange")
```

How do I filter recipes to return only the rows in which recipes$title contains anything from fruits?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_detect` with `filter` after creating a single string from 'fruits' `collapse`d by `|` (OR)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
recipes %>%
       filter(str_detect(title, str_c(fruits, collapse="|")))
#  V1             title
#1  1         apple pie
#2  3     peach strudel
#3  4      banana split
#4  7 peaches and cream
#5  8      baked apples
```

Comment: This gives me the error "Error: Evaluation error: argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)". This occurs even if I explicitly convert the columns from factors to character vectors e.g. 

fruit_recipes <- recipes %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, ~as.character(.)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(title, str_c(fruits, collapse="|")))

Any idea how I could resolve this?

Comment: @Mel  I was using only your example and it is working fine for me with `factor` column as well

Comment: @Mel Try `recipes %>% filter(str_detect(as.character(title), str_c(as.character(fruits), collapse="|")))`