# Filtering rows based on partial matching between a data frame and a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, match, partial

I have a data frame and want to filter it based on the partial match of names in the first column with the names in the vector.

```
nam <- c('mmu_mir-1-3p','mmu_mir-1-5p','mmu-mir-3-5p','mir-4','mmu-mir-6-3p') #factor
aa <- c('12854','36','5489','54485','2563') #numeric
df <- data.frame(nam,aa)

vector <- c('mir-1','mir-3','mir-6')
```

I need to have rows in the new data frame where names in `df$nam` are partially matching with the names in `vector`. So `new_df` should look like this.

```
new_nam <- c('mmu_mir-1-3p','mmu_mir-1-5p','mmu-mir-3-5p','mmu-mir-6-3p')  #factor
new_aa <- c('12854','36','5489','2563')  #numeric
new_df <- data.frame(new_nam,new_aa)
```

Comment: Not directly about the question, but why do you have numeric columns as strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use dplyr::filter() to return only rows where the value contains one or more of a given vector of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379098/how-to-use-dplyrfilter-to-return-only-rows-where-the-value-contains-one-or-m)

Comment: A few more examples (not exact duplicates, but similar ideas) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6947587/5325862)

Comment: The numeric column is not a value for the first column, they are supposed to be a string

Comment: Since the structure of the names are different, for some reasons I was losing several rows in my new df

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `paste` the elements of 'vector' into a single string collapsed by `|` and usse that in `grepl` or `str_detect` to `filter` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   filter(str_detect(nam, str_c(vector, collapse="|")))
#           nam    aa
#1 mmu_mir-1-3p 12854
#2 mmu_mir-1-5p    36
#3 mmu-mir-3-5p  5489
#4 mmu-mir-6-3p  2563
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `subset/grepl`

```
subset(df, grepl(paste(vector, collapse= "|"), nam))
```

Comment: similar base R `df[grep(paste(vector, collapse = "|"), df$nam), ]`

Comment: It works now, thanks, but I wondered what if we don't do collapsing, instead to write a code to grep names of the vector in df without considering any prefix or suffixes. Something like `*`-mir-1-`*` that is possible in `bash` which star represents `anything` can be at those positions.

Comment: @Apex the issue is the `pattern` in `grep` is not vectorized i.e. it takes only a pattern. of length 1.  that is the reason I collapsed to a single string wqith `|` meaning `OR`.  Otherwise, you can also loop i.e. `Reduce("|", lapply(vector,  grepl, x = df$nam))` and then `Reduce` with `|`

Comment: @akrun could you please clarify a bit more that collapsing with `|` into a string how come is helping `grep` to ignore `prefix` and `suffix` while matching?

Comment: @Apex It is looking for any of the words i.e. substring in a string and if it is present, then return TRUE or else FALSE i..e. it looks for mir-1, mir-3, ... in each of the string.  Probably better to have a word boundary as well to limit matching for edge cases